# Proper way to post to a servlet on Google App Engine from a Java client application

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, post, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have deployed an to App Engine. I setup SSL, and associated it with a custom domain. When I was developing the app locally, sending to a servlet via http://localhost:8080/servlet, worked as expected, but when I deploy it to App Engine, I have yet to get the appropriate result. I've tried many things, and the response codes I keep getting are either 404 or 500.

I startied with a simple HTTPUrlConnection and DataOutputstream to send a JSON to the servlet, and get an appropriate response. Like so:

```
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;  
    try {
        url = new URL(targetURL);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("custom-Header", "XYZ");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(urlParameters.length));
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");  

        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        //Send request
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(urlParameters);
        wr.flush ();
        wr.close ();

        //Get Response    
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer(); 
        while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
            response.append('\r');
        }
        rd.close();
        return response.toString();

    }
    finally {
        if(connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect(); 
        }
    }
```

This works locally.

I've now tried Apache Common's HttpAsyncClient, to check if it maybe a timing issue:

```
        final ResponseObject responseObject = new ResponseObject(); //my simple POJO

        try(CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpclient = HttpAsyncClients.custom()
            .setSSLStrategy(sslSessionStrategy)
            .build()) {

        httpclient.start();

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
        post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        post.setHeader("custom-Header", "XYZ");
        post.setHeader("Content-Language", "en-US");  

        HttpEntity entity = new ByteArrayEntity(urlParameters);
        post.setEntity(entity);

        final CountDownLatch latch1 = new CountDownLatch(1);
        httpclient.execute(post, new FutureCallback<HttpResponse>() {

            public void completed(final HttpResponse response) {
                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if (status >= 200 && status < 300) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    try {
                        responseObject.message = entity != null ? EntityUtils.toString(entity) : null;
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    responseObject.exception = new ClientProtocolException("Unexpected response status: " + status);
                }

                latch1.countDown();
            }

            public void failed(final Exception ex) {
                responseObject.exception = ex;
                latch1.countDown();
            }

            public void cancelled() {
                latch1.countDown();
            }

        });

        latch1.await();
        if(responseObject.exception != null) {
            throw responseObject.exception;
        } else {
            return responseObject.message;
        }
    }
```

This also works locally, but when trying to reach AppEngine, still no go.

Here's my simple web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>my.servlet.package.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>everything</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
<user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
</user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<welcome-file-list>  
    <welcome-file>home.jsp</welcome-file>  
</welcome-file-list>
```

Locally, I post to http://localhost:8080/login. As for App Engine, I posted to the ff:

- https://myapp.appspot.com/login
- https://myapp.customdomain.com/login

I've tried changing up the url-pattern. I started with **/login**, then did **login**, then explicitly tried the both App Engine and custom domain urls (i.e. myapp.appspot.com/login and myapp.mydomain.com/login). I also tried having an actual jsp or html page to post to, after trying not having an actual page associated with the servlet i.e. login.jsp or login.html.

When I used HttpAsyncClient (my choice due to SSLContext), the best result I got was the HTML of the page associated with the servlet, but never the response I need from the Servlet.

Any ideas?

Comment: anyone? no one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer on one of Google Cloud Platform's scattered docs: 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/how-requests-are-handled
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/how-requests-are-routed

Basically, you'll have to prepend your project's appspot url e.g. myapp.appspot.com, with the version ID of any actively serving instance of your app. You can find such IDs under the Versions page of your App Engine console. For example: https://versionId.myapp.appspot.com.